# Does there exist a boolean lattice without atoms?

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

There are atomic boolean lattices and this is the same as atomistic boolean lattices.

Does there exist a boolean lattice without atoms? (except of the degenerative case of one-element lattice)

Or at least give me an example of a non-atomic boolean lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the (atomic) Boolean algebra of all subsets of the set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers, and form a quotient algebra by identifying any two elements $a$ and $b$ whose symmetric difference $a\triangle b$ is finite.  The result is a Boolean algebra without atoms.

Comment: For another example, start with the Boolean algebra of Borel subsets of the real line, and form a quotient algebra by identifying any two whose symmetric difference has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Is this Boolean algebra a complete lattice?

Comment: @porton The example in my answer is not complete, but the one in my comment is complete.