# Two alleged counterexamples (about boolean algebras)

Tags: examples-counterexamples, order-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Trying to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1442432/4876), I propose two possible counter-examples. Please help me to understand whether these cases are really counter-examples.

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ be (fixed) boolean lattices (with lattice operations denoted $\sqcup$ and $\sqcap$, bottom element $\bot$ and top element $\top$).

I call a *boolean funcoid* a pair $(\alpha;\beta)$ of functions $\alpha:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}$, $\beta:\mathfrak{B}\rightarrow\mathfrak{A}$ such that (for every $X\in\mathfrak{A}$, $Y\in\mathfrak{B}$)
$$Y\sqcap^{\mathfrak{B}}\alpha(X)\ne\bot^{\mathfrak{B}} \Leftrightarrow X\sqcap^{\mathfrak{A}}\beta(Y)\ne\bot^{\mathfrak{A}}.$$

(Boolean funcoids are a special case of pointfree funcoids as defined in my [free ebook](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html).)

Order boolean funcoids by the formula
$$(\alpha_0;\beta_0)\le (\alpha_1;\beta_1) \Leftrightarrow \forall X\in\mathfrak{A}: \alpha_0(X)\le\alpha_1(X) \land \forall Y\in\mathfrak{B}: \beta_0(Y)\le\beta_1(Y).$$

Is the poset of boolean funcoids between the boolean lattice $\mathfrak{A}$ and itself also a boolean lattice, if...

1. $\mathfrak{A}$ is the boolean lattice (with $\mathord\sqcup=\mathord\cup$ and $\mathord\sqcap=\mathord\cap$) whose elements are finite unions of binary cartesian products $X\times Y$ for sets $X\in\mathscr{P}A$, $Y\in\mathscr{P}B$, where $A$ and $B$ are (fixed) infinite sets?
2. $\mathfrak{A}$ is the atomless boolean lattice from [this Andreas Blass's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1441264/4876)? By the way, is this atomless lattice complete?
3. $\mathfrak{A}$ is the atomless boolean lattice from the comment to above mentioned Andreas Blass's answer?

Comment: 2 and 3 are false. See https://portonmath.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/pointfree-topology-negative-result/